# Display PDF Stored in Static Resources in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, static-resources

I currently have a VF Page that displays a Link to a PDF stored in Static Resources. I am using this VF Page to override standard SFDC help.

Users clicks "help for this page" | VF Page displayed | User Clicks Link to PDF in Static Resource

Is there a way to simply display the PDF when a user clicks help for this page rather than forcing them to click a link within a VF Page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

(re: comments, I've misread the "*I currently have a VF Page...*")

Help for custom objects won't let you put a static resource there but you could try to make-do with "action" parameter?

```
<apex:page readonly="true" action="{!$Resource.resource_name}">
</apex:page>
```

This should redirect immediately.

---

**Original**

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_sectionHeader.htm

> **help**
>
> The URL for the page's help file. When this value is specified, a Help
>   for this Page link automatically appears on the right side of the
>   colored title bar. The URL must be a fully-qualified, absolute, or
>   relative URL; JavaScript URLs aren't permitted. Invalid URLs display a
>   warning icon instead of the help link.

So if any link can be used in the "help" attribute and it can even point to external website (absolute URL):

```
<apex:sectionHeader title="..." subtitle="..." help="{!$Resource.resource_name}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I am understanding this correctly this would be useful if I was overriding the standard controller with a customer visual force page.  I am not overriding the stand controller. I am overriding the help page identified in the Custom Object Setup. Does this make sense?

Comment: nice, can also take advantage of `apex:pageBlock` which has `helpUrl` and `helpTitle` attributes